# Powershell new array from concatenation of one word with another array

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, I'm trying to make a list of files to be excluded from various commands that take exclusion parameters, e.g. `Get-ChildItem`.

The files I'm dealing with belong to various projects and represent sequential page numbers such that for a given project A, it would have files `projA.1`, `projA.2`, etc. I'd like to be able to make one list of *page numbers* (not files) to be excluded, but apply that list to multiple projects, so I feel like what I want to do is have an array of excluded page numbers that then get concatendated onto the project name and passed as an exclusion parameter. However, I don't know if there's a compact way to do this. Here's what I have so far:

```
# Source and destination projects with files named projA.1, projA.2,...,projA.n, etc. 
$sourceProject = "projA"
$destProject = "projB"

# List of pages which will be excluded
$pageExclusions =@( 
"1",
"27",
"28",
"29",
"30",
"31",
"32",
"33",
"34",
"35",
"36",
"37",
"38",
"40")

$sourceExclusions = @()
foreach($i in $pageExclusions){
    $sourceExclusions = $sourceExclusions + ($sourceProject + "." +  $i)
}

# ... later I will use $sourceExclusions as an exclude filter, e.g.:
Get-ChildItem projA.* -Exclude $sourceExclusions

# and I'd need to repeat the same for projB
```

In my code example, is there a compact notation to say "`sourceExclusions` is a new array such that is is the same length as `$pageExclusions` but each entry is the filename `projA` with the corresponding extension from `$pageExclusions`"?

Or, even better yet, is there a way to pass them both to an exclude parameter directly in a way it will interpret to result in `$sourceExclusions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you thinking of something like this?

```
Get-ChildItem -Exclude ($pageExclusions | % { "$sourceProject.$_","$destProject.$_" })
```

This will exclude `projA.1`, `projB.1` etc. 
If you still need it only return files mathing `projA.*` and `projB.*` you can extend it like this

```
Get-ChildItem -Exclude ($pageExclusions | % { "$sourceProject.$_","$destProject.$_" }) | ? { $_.Name -match "$sourceProject\.|$destProject\." }
```